# .NET 3.5 alternative to Silverlight 4 and .Net 4.0. WCF RIA Services

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I developed a Silverlight 4.0 application in .Net 4.0 with WCF RIA Services.

2 days ago I published my web site. I was getting too many errors.
The Hosting Support representative told me that they have only .Net 3.5 support.
As version 3.5 does not have WCF RIA Services, I need advice on what would be the best and easiest way to solve my problem? What is an alternative technology for WCF RIA services in .Net 3.5 that my service can be converted to?

The server is using IIS version 6

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what specific parts of WCF RIA and .NET 4 you're using. You haven't provided a lot of information. But the most logical way, it seems, would be to convert to a .NET 3.5 WCF service.

I don't have any experience with this, so you might want to investigate how much work this would be. Perhaps it is more interesting to get .NET 4.0 hosting.